# Geb with Selenoid - new session for each test in a class/spec

Tags: groovy, spock, geb, selenoid

Currently trying to run Geb tests on Selenoid docker instance. I want Selenoid to generate video reports for each test in a class/spec, but it seems like Geb runs all the tests in one driver session therefore Selenoid generates a single video for all of them.

I've tried different combinations of driver caching configurations like

```
cacheDriver = false
quitDriverOnBrowserReset = false
```

or calling CachingDriverFactory.clearCacheAndQuitDriver() on cleanup

but it's either all tests using the same instance or the second test fails with "Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

Is it possible to have separate selenoid videos for each test in a class/spec?

Comment: Have you tried to set `cacheDriver = false`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, misspelled it in my question, I have tried `cacheDriver = false`

Comment: It is possible to have separate Selenoid videos for each test in a class/spec. You can try achieving this by creating a new WebDriver instance for each test and properly handling the driver's lifecycle.

Comment: Every web driver instance is a separate Selenoid session. Just make sure your framework is creating a new driver instance for each test case. This is not directly related to Selenoid.

Comment: @BrixxonTulabing Yes, I see, it seems like my problem is creating a new WebDriver before each test properly in accordance to Geb/Spock lifecycle

Comment: You need to set `cacheDriver = false` but `quitDriverOnBrowserReset = true`, not both to false, or just omit quitDriverOnBrowserReset` as it will default to `true` when  `cacheDriver = false`.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings `quitDriverOnBrowserReset = true` makes `sessionId` of a `WebDriver` `null`. However, it seems like Geb creates new driver only if `WebDriver` object itself is `null`. I've managed to solve my issue by checking `sessionId` in `startup()` and turning `WebDriver` object to `null`.

Comment: You are most likely facing https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/677, that's why you had to set the driver to `null` to work around it, @КонстантинТонков.

Comment: @erdi Yes, looks like it!